# How to Return a Table That Was Created Within Function?

Tags: plpgsql

I have a PL/pgSQL function that creates a table.  I would like to return the table that was created as part of a "Return Table" function.  Here is an example of the type of function I'm talking about:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_schema.new_foo_table(character varying)
  RETURNS table(row_id bigint, 
         catalog_id varchar, 
         value numeric(5,4)) AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
v_table_name ALIAS FOR $1;
cmd            text;

BEGIN
  cmd := 'CREATE TABLE '||v_table_name||' 
          (row_id bigint, 
           catalog_id varchar, 
           value numeric(5,4))';
  EXECUTE cmd;

  cmd := 'INSERT INTO '||v_table_name||'
          SELECT row_id, catalog_id, sum(value)
          FROM other_table
          GROUP BY row_id, catalog_id';
  EXECUTE cmd;

  RETURN --results of select * from v_table_name;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

How would I return the results of the new table I created?  I'm guess the return would have to use some type of dynamic SQL "execute" statement since the name of the newly created table is in a variable.

Comment: yes, PLpgSQL has statement RETURN QUERY EXECUTE http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this can be done using RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'command string'.  For your example it would look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_schema.new_foo_table(character varying)
  RETURNS table(row_id bigint, 
          catalog_id varchar, 
          value numeric(5,4)) AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
arg_table_name ALIAS FOR $1;
v_table_name   varchar;
cmd            text;

BEGIN
  v_table_name := quote_ident(arg_table_name);
  cmd := 'CREATE TABLE '||v_table_name||' 
          (row_id bigint, 
           catalog_id varchar, 
           value numeric(5,4))';
  EXECUTE cmd;

  cmd := 'INSERT INTO '||v_table_name||'
          SELECT row_id, catalog_id, sum(value)
          FROM other_table
          GROUP BY row_id, catalog_id';
  EXECUTE cmd;

  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'select * from v_table_name';
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

For additional information see section 40.6.1.2. in the POSTGRESQL documentation: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING

Comment: **this function is SQLinjection vulnerable** - the v_table_name isn't escaped - you should to use `quote_ident` function.